# Switching Career Areas

Tags: career-development, software-development, software, quality

I'm soon to graduate in BSCS and doing an 6 month Quality Assurance internship, currently in 3 month. I started of QA because I found it interesting because of automation. But after working I've realized Quality Assurance is not my cup of tea. Especially because in my country QA is more of a manual job than automated. There's not much horizontal growth in QA here.

I'm a programmer through and through, I'm good at it too. Not being able to write code is making me unhappy & noneffective at my work place, I don't feel satisfied at all. I feel like a weak resource. I've discussed this concern with my boss too. He just shrugged it off saying, it's not my job to evaluate myself. I want my career development to be in software development

NOW MY PROBLEM IS: After graduation, I'll apply for a developer's job. Would my experience as a QA make me less likely a candidate? Should I leave QA asap before it hurts my prospects further?

Comment: Related but not quite duplicate - [Can bad working experience really hurt your career?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10930/can-bad-working-experience-really-hurt-your-career)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apply for a developer position, but finish your QA

*From my experience*

Hey, you're studying CS, so? An employer will look at your resume and see that aside from studying Computer Science, you've been doing QA. **That's not bad**. During my internship I did Flash and Flex UX development, and it didn't affect or make a condition of my future. I simply skipped any offer that targeted Fl* afterwards, and it was just fine. Just expect that if a task arrives at the company somehow related to your internship, it may be dropped onto you. That could be less than 5% of the job, but anyway **that could be a plus for the employer to hire you.**

What you have to learn on internships is more about the business relationship side, rather than learning a lot how to code (actually, that's *assumed* by employers. *You have a BS, you know*). It will be, realistically, the first time you have a boss (professors are not bosses), so **if the internship went well, that's good for you and your career**.

So, my advice. Make sure you end up your internship correctly. Suggest about automating QA, if that would be more enjoyable (it definitely is more sensible), offer pro's and con's, but don't push it or make it your only goal if not accepted by the bosses. In internship evaluations at college, they tend to also write down if you've been proactive, hard worker and team player.

*Note: of course, if doing those 3 months left of internship could make you fall in a depression, then leave! This was just my opinion from my point of view.*

Comment: I did make the suggestion about automation a month or more before. And my boss said okay but nothing of sort has been implied. There used to be automation here, but not anymore IDK why. I'm in deep depression because I'm afraid this might effect my career negatively.

Comment: Another question: Would it be wise to continue QA after grad till a development job comes along, just to stay in the market & industry?

Comment: @ZairaZafar shoot, if you're deeply depressed you should seek for medical help, but in case you are _"only"_ worried about your future career, don't be. You are barely starting, and even after years, you can switch to another position. Just take some courses fully tight to what you want to do, pass them, do open source projects using this new tech stack, and apply for those positions. Experience? 6 months of internship gives you "job experience", but development experience takes much more time and passion.

Comment: Also, they may have missed the whole picture of automating QA. Just drop "hey, I was thinking of automate this **small** part of the test. It will allow other developers run this test on their own much faster and I'll be able to focus on other more critical parts" or similar. If you focus on the advantage of "you working more", it may be a good way to catch your boss' eyes. If he's ok with the change, you might even end up enjoying the intricates of stubbing, user/behavior/unit-testing and so. If not, just finish the internship and look for another job. It won't harm your career

Comment: They're aware of Automation benefits, but recently lack the time for continuous implementation, which I feel is abit impractical because yes it's time consuming but worth it and beneficial in far future. Automation is treated as extraneous work here. By here I mean my country.

Comment: @ZairaZafar anytime. One last thing... which is your country?

Comment: Pakistan is my country

Answer (score 0):

> After graduation, I'll apply for a developer's job. Would my
>   experience as a QA make me less likely a candidate?

No.

As a new graduate with experience, you'll be competing against other new graduates - some with no experience at all.

While having development experience might be ideal, *all* experience has value. You know how to work, take directions, produce output, etc. Hopefully, you'll have a good recommendation from your boss. Those are all positives.

> Should I leave QA asap before it hurts my prospects further?

If the alternative is not working at all - that would be foolish both financially and professionally.

If the alternative is a software development internship, if might be good.

QA work isn't hurting your prospects. Don't abandon it unless you have something better to do.

Comment: Someone said on a question I found here, "Gap is better than time in QA. Employeers are okay with a gap and can deal with it. But QA is not development at all and you might have issues getting hired" or something similar.